# Adding tapGesture to a label over an imageView whose userInteraction is disabled

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

i'm new to iOS development.
I have an imageView.On tapping on any point on the imageView,i'm creating a label at that point.After that ,i want to have a delete option for that label on tapping that newly created label(This time i dont want to create the label again.so i disabled the userinteraction of imageView).But the tap action is not working since i disabled the userinteraction on image view.When i enable it,call to tap on label function is working fine,but a new label is being adding on that point.
i'm attaching the code below. i'm using swift 3.0
Please help me.

```
import UIKit

class Tagging: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchControllerDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating{

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    let labelTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    var taggedPersonNameLabel = UILabel()
    var pointingToNotation = TriangleView()
     var searchController : UISearchController!

    @IBOutlet var imageToBeTagged: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageToBeTagged.image = imageToUploadAfterFiltering
        tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedOnImage))
        imageToBeTagged.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        imageToBeTagged.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        //creating done btn
        let next = UIButton(type: .custom)
        next.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
        next.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30)
        next.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doneBtnAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        let nxtBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: next)

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nxtBtn

        //adding tap gesture to who's this label for giving delete tag action
        tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteTag))

        taggedPersonNameLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        taggedPersonNameLabel.addGestureRecognizer(labelTapGesture)
    }

    func doneBtnAction(){

        let _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    func deleteTag() {
        print("oohhyaaaahhh")
    }

    func tappedOnImage(){

         let point = tapGesture.location(in: tapGesture.view)

        if point.x < 100 {
             // triangle view class is defined in uitility  files folder
            pointingToNotation = TriangleView(frame: CGRect(x:point.x + 5, y:point.y - 3, width:10, height:6))
            pointingToNotation.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.imageToBeTagged.addSubview(pointingToNotation )
            //to show pop without going out beyond 0
             taggedPersonNameLabel = UILabel(frame : CGRect(x:point.x , y: point.y + 3,  width: 100, height: 25))

        }else if point.x > 100 && point.x < UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100{

            pointingToNotation = TriangleView(frame: CGRect(x:point.x, y:point.y - 3, width:10, height:6))
            pointingToNotation.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.imageToBeTagged.addSubview(pointingToNotation )

        taggedPersonNameLabel = UILabel(frame : CGRect(x:point.x - 50  , y: point.y + 3,  width: 100, height: 25))

        }
        else{
            pointingToNotation = TriangleView(frame: CGRect(x:point.x - 15, y:point.y - 3, width:10, height:6))
            pointingToNotation.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.imageToBeTagged.addSubview(pointingToNotation )
        //to show pop up without going outside the screen width
            taggedPersonNameLabel = UILabel(frame : CGRect(x:point.x - 100  , y: point.y + 3,  width: 100, height: 25))

        }
        taggedPersonNameLabel.textAlignment = .center
        taggedPersonNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        taggedPersonNameLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        taggedPersonNameLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        taggedPersonNameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        taggedPersonNameLabel.text = "Who's this?"
        self.imageToBeTagged.addSubview(taggedPersonNameLabel)

        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
        self.definesPresentationContext = true

        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField

        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.imageToBeTagged.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        //this is used to hide search bar.
        // self.searchController.searchBar.isHidden = true

    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {


    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u adding the target for gesture twice for `tapGesture` change it to `labelTapGesture`

```
    imageToBeTagged.image = imageToUploadAfterFiltering
    //added the action to tap on image          
    tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedOnImage))

    imageToBeTagged.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    imageToBeTagged.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    //creating done btn
    let next = UIButton(type: .custom)
    next.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    next.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30)
    next.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doneBtnAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    let nxtBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: next)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nxtBtn

    //adding tap gesture to who's this label for giving delete tag action
    //label tap to delete the tag
    labelTapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteTag))//change hear

    taggedPersonNameLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    taggedPersonNameLabel.addGestureRecognizer(labelTapGesture)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response brother..But my bad luck

Comment: then add gestures to newly created label